# Why are some commands 'non-existent'?

Tags: linux, command-line, troubleshooting

I'm a fairly new Linux user and I've noticed that some commands are only available to the superuser - shutdown for example. I often get confused when I know there's a command, try to execute it but get told it doesn't even exist - yet all I needed was to be root to execute it.

My question is why don't these commands say that you don't have enough privileges to run it, or say that you need to be root? Is there some technical reason for this or is it just the way it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The response you are probably seeing indicates not that the commands don't exist, but that they "aren't found":

```
telemachus ~ $ ifconfig -a
bash: ifconfig: command not found
```

Some error messages are useless, but this one is actually relatively helpful. The words "not found" tell you where the problem is. Your shell (in my case it's Bash, clearly) looks for commands along its `$PATH` variable. The `PATH` is a set of colon-separated values. Each value is a directory where executable (binary) programs go, and the shell looks for commands in order from left to right along that chain of directories. Here's how to see what your PATH is:

```
telemachus ~ $ echo $PATH
/home/telemachus/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games
```

(Note that case matters, PATH is all upper. Also the `$` matters.) So my shell looks for commands in the `bin` directory in my home folder, then in `/usr/local/bin`, then in `/usr/bin` etc. The order matters, because sometimes you will have two versions of one program, and you want to make sure that you find a specific one first. (I have a different version of Ruby in my `$HOME/bin` directory than the system-wide one, and I want it found first.)

To add a directory to your PATH, you can normally edit your shell's profile. Depending on what distribution of Linux you are using, that file will be called `.profile` or `.bash_profile`, and it will be in your home directory. Files that start with a `.` (often called dot-files) are hidden by default. They won't show up in a gui file-manager, and the `ls` command won't see them (without help). To see what's present in your home, open a shell (you will be in your home directory by default in a new shell), and type **ls -A**. The **-A** flag tells the **ls** command to show hidden files. You should see either `.profile` or `.bash_profile`, which you can then edit. Add a colon and the full path of the directory you want (a full path should start with a `/` to indicate its position from the root of your drive). You don't want a colon after the last value. So if you have a normal PATH, you can add `/sbin` this way:

```
PATH=$PATH:/sbin
```

However, all of this said, you still can't get directly at `/sbin/shutdown` that way:

```
telemachus ~ $ /sbin/shutdown -h now
shutdown: you must be root to do that!
```

By giving the command's full path, I "found" the command, but I still couldn't run it. Some commands, like `shutdown`, require special privileges. To get permission to issue `shutdown` from a shell, you would need to use `su` or `sudo` depending on what kind of system you're on. I've already written a novel, so that's a story for another day.

Answer (score 6):

The reason they are "non-existent" is because their location is not in our PATH environment variable.  You can see the directories in your PATH by typing:

```
echo $PATH
```

and you can check the location of your command by typing

```
whereis shutdown
```

typically you will see that the directory of the command you are looking for is not in your PATH.  You can add directories to your path by adding the following lines in your login script (~/.bash_profile).

```
PATH=$PATH:/my/new/directory
export PATH
```

Answer (score 3):

They are stored in `/usr/sbin` or `/sbin` directories which are not included in the user's `PATH` variable (by default).

Answer (score 1):

Think about linux as a multiuser system and it will makes sense. You don't want the machine you're working on to be shut down by an other *user*. If root does it well, maybe he has some good reason to shut down it.

As user you *should* be able to do things that affect only your space. If you run linux as desktop (and you say you're new to it) you're probably running something like Ubuntu or similar. In these distributions you can use the gui to use almost everything and the system will ask you the password when needed.

On console you can get root access by using `su` command (if you know root's password) or `sudo su` if your distro uses sudo. After that you will have all the powers and privileges you need to break your system :P